# TextInput ignores Double Tap (Period) on React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, textinput

I have TextInput component, where it changes the state whenever user types, but I realise due to the value of TextInput using this.state.text as value, double-tapping on space does not produce period on iOs.

Is there a work around to this so double tapping on space can still produce period on ios?

```
 onChange =(text) => {
    this.setState({text});
 }




<TextInput
          onChangeText={this.onChange}
          onSubmitEditing={this.onSubmit}
          value={this.state.text}
          autoCapitalize="sentences"
          blurOnSubmit={false}
          editable={true}
        />
```

Comment: Note, it does produce periods when multiline is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, TouchableOpacity, View, TextInput } from 'react-native';

class UselessTextInput extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            lastPress: 0
        }
    }

    onPress = () => {
        var delta = new Date().getTime() - this.state.lastPress;

        if (delta < 200) {
            alert("DOUBLE TAP")
            // double tap happend
        }

        this.setState({
            lastPress: new Date().getTime()
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onPress}>
                <TextInput
                    pointerEvents="none"
                />
            </TouchableOpacity>
        );
    }
}

export default class UselessTextInputMultiline extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            text: 'Useless Multiline Placeholder',
        };
    }

    // If you type something in the text box that is a color, the background will change to that
    // color.
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{
                backgroundColor: this.state.text,
                borderBottomColor: '#000000',
                borderBottomWidth: 1
            }}
            >
                <UselessTextInput
                    multiline={true}
                    numberOfLines={4}
                    onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({ text })}
                    value={this.state.text}
                />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

// skip these lines if using Create React Native App
AppRegistry.registerComponent(
    'AwesomeProject',
    () => UselessTextInputMultiline
);
```

You can edit it based on your requirements I've tried it on react native docs site and it worked.

Comment: i meant double tab on spacebar gives u a period

Answer (score 1):

onChange event on the textInput field causes problems e.g. Keyboard short cuts (double tap on space to create a period(.)) since the state is change on per keystroke and keyboard cannot capture the doublespace.

**So instead of storing the value in the state, I just capture it onSubmitEditing, capturing the final values.**

```
   <TextInput
      onSubmitEditing={this.onSubmit}
      value={this.state.text}
      placeholder="Say Something.."
      blurOnSubmit={false}
      editable={true}
    />
```

Then we create a submit function that does something with the text and clear the field.

```
  onSubmit = (e) => {

    const text = e.nativeEvent.text;

    this.setState({text}, () => { // <- Important Callback after setstate

          //Whatever U want to do with the data here.

          this.setState({text: ''}) // clear the field (this must be in the callback)

    })
  }
```

> We set the this.state.text to text so we can set it back to '' after
>   call back. If you don't do this step, state is not change, and the
>   component doesn't refresh with a empty field.

**I realise with this method, all the keyboard functions will work as per normal, including double-space for periods(.), and even copy and paste values, without using setState.**

**Update: multiline enabled Solution.**

The above works for single line, for multiline where we don't use onSubmitEditing and uses button instead, we need to add a ref to the text input.

```
    <TextInput
      ref={input => { this.textMessage = input }} //Important.
      //onSubmitEditing={this.onSubmit} //Remove so we can use newline
      value={this.state.text}
      placeholder="Say Something.."
      blurOnSubmit={false}
      editable={true}
      multiline={true}
    />
```

Create a button that does the submit

```
<Button onPress={this.onSubmit} 
  title="Send"
/>
```

There's a different way to get the value via reference for the onSubmit function

```
  onSubmit = () => {

    const text = this.textMessage._lastNativeText.trim(); //Remember the ref from textInput?
    this.setState({text}, () => {
       //Do whatever u want with the text here
       this.setState({text: ''}) //clear the field
       this.textMessage._lastNativeText = ''; //you need to clear this too
    })
```

> Note: If you don't set this.textMessage._lastNativeText to empty, you
>   will keep submitting the previous value when you click on the Send
>   button even though the textInput looks empty visually.

Answer (score 1):

This is very close to the apple behavior. If anyone could find a way that it is not feature parity with apple, let me know.

```
import {useRef} from "react";

const useTextInputReplacer = () => {
  const lastText = useRef<string>("");
  const lastSpaceEnteredAt = useRef<number>();
  const periodReplaceDisabled = useRef<boolean>(true);

  const isLastCharacterAlphaNumeric = str => str[str.length - 1].match(/[a-zA-Z0-9]/);

  return (_text) => {
    if (lastText.current && _text.length) {
      if (lastText.current.length < _text.length) {  // add case
        if (_text[_text.length - 1] === " " && !periodReplaceDisabled.current) {
          const now = new Date().getTime();
          if (lastSpaceEnteredAt.current && (now - lastSpaceEnteredAt.current) < 300) {
            lastSpaceEnteredAt.current = undefined;
            _text = _text.replace(/\s{2}$/, ". ");
            periodReplaceDisabled.current = true;
          } else if (!periodReplaceDisabled.current && isLastCharacterAlphaNumeric(lastText.current)) {
            lastSpaceEnteredAt.current = now;
          }
        } else {
          periodReplaceDisabled.current = !isLastCharacterAlphaNumeric(lastText.current);
        }
      } else if (lastText.current.length > _text.length) { // deletion case
        periodReplaceDisabled.current = lastText.current[lastText.current.length - 1] === "." || !isLastCharacterAlphaNumeric(_text);
      }
    }
    lastText.current = _text;
    return _text;
  };
};
```

Then in your component

```
  const textInputReplacer = useTextInputReplacer();

<Input 
   onChangeText={text => updateText(textInputReplacer(text))}
/>
```